# Contacts not enrolling in Automation Plan in XP Scaled topology

Tags: xconnect, azure, marketing-automation, api

I am using events to enrol contacts in a Marketing Automation plan, and it works fine in XP Single topology, but in an XP Scaled topology (Azure PaaS) the contacts are not being enrolled.

The plan is set to Active and has not expired. I have verified that the contact has the event in its Interactions data (via xConnect OData API) and I can see the contact in the AutomationPool database table at the time the event was triggered, but the contact remains in the pool and never gets enrolled. The value in the *Attempts* column for all contacts is 0. There are no records in the other Marketing Automation database tables.

The xConnect collection, xConnect search, and Marketing Automation Operations Azure app services are not throwing any errors in Application Insights.

What might prevent a contact from being enrolled in the plan ?

Environment: Sitecore 9.1 Update 1, Azure Search, MS Azure PaaS XP Scaled.

Comment: I see you checked the ma ops app service, but did you you confirm the webjob is running ok? You should be able to check its status and log in Kudu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the Marketing Automation Engine webjob is not running properly. This is an executable that, in Azure Paas, runs as a webjob in the MAops app service (for XP Scaled topologies) and responsible for enrolling contacts in plans and activities.

You can confirm it's running status in the webjobs blade in Azure portal. You can also restart it here if needed.  Additionally you can get more detailed information on the status and logs in Kudu via the "Webjobs Dashboard". This may help diagnose why the job is not starting correctly (eg. config issue, license issue etc)

Some more information on the data flows in the Sitecore docs:
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/marketing-automation-engine.html

Comment: Thanks George, troubleshooting via the webjob blade as per your answer identified that there was an issue with the config XML. Turns out a tab had crept into the beginning of the AppSettings file which prevented startup. Cheers.